# Need help aligning divs with CSS

Tags: html, css

This is where I want the divs.

[image: Example of desired result]

This is what the browser is doing:

[image: Example of actual result]

Right now I have the divs set to have a maximum of three in a "row." However, the 2nd row of divs are forced under the longest in the first. I'm not sure how to make them go where I want them.Any help is appreciated!

**Here is my code:**

```css
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0vw;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(../Images/background.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0vw;
    padding: 0vw;
    
}
h1 {
    color: transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(../Images/background.png) repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    font-size: 2.25vw;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.8vw;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.1vw;
}

/* ID Section */
#NavandTitleBar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.1vw;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
#NavandTitleBar nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.01vw;
}
#NavandTitleBar nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#NavandTitleBar nav ul li a h3 {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(../Images/background.png) repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
}
#navHome {
    position: absolute;
    left: 4%;
    top: 4%;
 }
 #navGallery {
    position: absolute;
    left: 12%;
    top: 4%;
}
#navAbout {
    position: absolute;
    right: 12%;
    top: 4%;
}
#navContact {
    position: absolute;
    right: 4%;
    top: 4%;
}

#main div{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin: 2vw;
    width: 20vw;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1vw 3vw;
    text-align: justify;
    border-radius: 0.5vw;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
    animation: fadein 2s;
}
#main div p {
    color: #555555;
}
#main div .completionDate {
    color: #999999;
}

/* Classes */
.username {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    border: 1px solid #bdb6bd;
    cursor: text;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding: 1vw 2vw;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    top: 10vw;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    
}
.password {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    border: 1px solid #bdb6bd;
    cursor: text;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding: 1vw 2vw;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    top: 10.5vw;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

.submitbutton {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bdb6bd;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding: 1vw 6.18vw;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    top: 11vw;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

/* Animations */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head> 
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Project Alyssa</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/CascadingStyleSheet/project_alyssa.css"/>
            <link rel="icon" href="Resources/Images/project_alyssa.ico"/>
            <script src="Resources/JavaScript/project_alyssa.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="NavandTitleBar">
                <nav id="leftNav">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="navHome"><a href="project_alyssa.html"><h3>Home</h3></a></li>
                        <li id="navGallery"><a href="Secondary/gallery.html"><h3>Gallery</h3></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <h1>Project Alyssa</h1>
                <nav id="rightNav">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="navAbout"><a href="Secondary/about.html"><h3>About</h3></a></li>
                        <li id="navContact"><a href="Secondary/contact.html"><h3>Contact</h3></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="introduction">
                    <h2>Blah</h2>
                    <p>
                        Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="hope">
                    <h2>Blah Blah Blah</h2>
                        <p>
                            Hello World.
                        </p>
                </div>
                <div id="theday">
                    <h2>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</h2>
                    <p>
                        Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. 
                    </p>
                    <p class="completionDate">
                        Hello World.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="ithink">
                    <h2>Blah Blah Blah Blah</h2>
                    <p>
                        Hello World.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="stupidthings">
                    <h2>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</h2>
                    <p>
                        Hello World.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="blahblah">
                    <h2>Blah Blah Blah.</h2>
                    <p>
                        Hello World.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear because you have an html with data on each row of a table and then ask something about horizontal alignment. Can you make a reproducible code snippet or jsfiddle with your problem?

Comment: @TigOldBitties Finished the code snippet. Sorry about the lack of it before.

Comment: If you run your snippet it doesn't produce the problem. I'll try to give you a hand.

Comment: Have a look at this page http://alex707.dlinkddns.com:7071/test2 and describe exactly what your problem is.

Comment: @TigOldBitties It does for me [link](http://imgur.com/JSo4VSc) and [link](http://imgur.com/XzQOJtl) I should note that my resolution is 2880x1800. I've used percentages on my alignment so I think it will look a little different on other displays.

Comment: @TigOldBitties This is what I get when i visit your site. [Top Part](http://imgur.com/498XxM5) and [Bottom Part](http://imgur.com/gxOko1m)

Comment: @TigOldBitties I need to move the table rows directly under the top ones. The closest representation of what I'm trying to do is [Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/search/cookies) If you scroll down a little bit you'll see how everything is directly under each other. That's for the most part what I'm trying to create with a table

Comment: That's what you told it to do. First of all, using table with cells with "display: inline-block;" is pointless and confusing. Your table cells are behaving like divs, whereas you table structure suggests that it should be one structure per row. Remove "display: inline-block" from css to understand what I mean.  The tumbler example is what you should have put in your question and now i understand what you mean. Be right back with an answer.

Comment: @TigOldBitties I see what you're saying about inline-block. If I were to change it would I just replace the table with divs? I guess I could place everything into its own div. I would have to set a maximum width in a parent tag because I don't want them to align edge to edge.

Comment: To achieve that layout, like at Tumblr, you'll need script, where I think [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is the most known, or dig in yourself, using `flexbox` and script.

Comment: @JoshHuskey See my answer for a similar effect, without using the absolutely positioned approach tumblr's framework uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tumbler effect you're trying to achieve is not going to happen with your structure, because you're using table cells displayed as inline blocks, which has the particular effect you describe as your "problem".

If you update your html using div, the closest you can get is the float left behavior of divs.

My guess is what you're going for is something like https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/card which you can do using columns in an easier fashion.

```
So
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f6tm2djf/2/) fiddle It uses 3 columns but you can use however many or few columns you need, in which you can add your items one in each column in order so they flow like you want them.

Comment: You are 100% correct in what I am going for. I'll get to work on changing those to divs and columns. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table  id="homeTable" align="center" >
......
</table>
```

if you need it in full width
use

```
<table  id="homeTable" align="center" style="width:100%" >
......
</table>
```

Comment: This might answer the question, though does not change anything what so ever making the posted code layout as requested. Also, no explanation to either why it work or how to make OP's code work, and further more, the `align` attribute is not supported in HTML5 (posted doctype shows that)

Comment: I tried this and didn't see an effect at all. Thanks anyway though.